# AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'timestamp'

Tags: python, python-2.7, timestamp

I am struggling to get my code running. There seems to be a problem with the timestamp. Do you have any suggestions to how I could change my code? 
I saw that this had been asked before, but did not manage to make it work.

This is the error I get when running the code: `'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'timestamp'`

My code:

```
import quandl, math, datetime

last_date = df.iloc[-1].name
last_unix = last_date.timestamp()
one_day = 86400 #Seconds in a day
next_unix = last_unix + one_day


for i in forecast_set: 
    next_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(next_unix)
    next_unix += one_day
    df.loc[next_date]=[np.nan for _ in range(len(df.columns)-1)]+[i]
    #Loop to replace all numbers on x axis with dates
```

Comment: *"saw that this had been asked before"* - where? *"but did not manage to make it work"* - be more specific.

Comment: I agree with jonrsharpe, and please clean your code so it is an (else) working example. Is df a pandas data frame? Then you might add pandas as a tag. Where does it fail? - I guess in last_date.timestamp()? Then the rest of the code would not be relevant here.

Comment: You might have a look at https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17329

Answer (score 6):

You can try this:

```
import time
.....
last_unix = time.mktime(last_date.timetuple())
```

That worked for me!

Comment: Nice! This is the correct answer. @Mikebarson Do you know why?

Comment: @Mr.Concolato Hi! It's been a while since I've posted this answer. And I'm so sorry, but right now I've forgotten why this worked. If you can help me remember that would be great!

Comment: Not completely sure, but I think it has something to do with the version (2.7 vs. 3.0) of python you are running. The above answer worked for me in 2.7.

Comment: @Mr.Concolato I see. I'll check this out soon and hopefully give a more detailed explanation as to why it worked.

Comment: It was the correct way to obtain the timestamp in the qpython interpreter running on an Android smartphone. Currently, the qpython environment executes python 3.2, which causes this kind of headache !

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but with Python 3.4 and I used the following solution.

```
last_unix = (last_date - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. I've needed to provide an access to `timestamp` in both: python2 and python3 environments (`timestamps` wasn't the main purpose of my module).

After several attempts to provide compatibility, I have installed **[`arrow`](https://pypi.org/project/arrow/) package**. It is already tested, pypi-published, and it works on many version of Python.

#### Install

Install from PyPI

```
pip install arrow
```

Or add to dependencies

#### Use in code

```python
import arrow
import quandl, math, datetime

last_date = df.iloc[-1].name
# use arrow
last_unix = arrow.get(last_date).timestamp
one_day = 86400 #Seconds in a day
next_unix = last_unix + one_day

# ... your code ...
```

Also, there are a lot of nifty and useful features (for example - no more tortures with time zones).